# cisco interface counters, multi string values

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ipython

want to extract RX, TX counters separately. Any python example to print counters in the following way from the string_output?

```
RX_unicast_packets = 2735118
RX_multicast_packets = 703555

TX_unicast_packets = 3983205
TX_multicast_packets = 1916649


RX
    2735118 unicast packets  703555 multicast packets  677 broadcast packets
    3439365 input packets  3803190483 bytes
    1867301 jumbo packets  0 storm suppression bytes
    0 runts  0 giants  0 CRC  0 no buffer
    0 input error  0 short frame  0 overrun   0 underrun  0 ignored
    0 watchdog  0 bad etype drop  0 bad proto drop  0 if down drop
    0 input with dribble  291 input discard
    15 Rx pause
  TX
    3983205 unicast packets  1916649 multicast packets  340 broadcast packets
    5900194 output packets  3546311266 bytes
    1702539 jumbo packets
    0 output errors  0 collision  0 deferred  0 late collision
    0 lost carrier  0 no carrier  0 babble 0 output discard
    0 Tx pause
"
```

Comment: You will attract more assistance by attempting at least an outline solution to your problem and including the code (with any error messages) in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the regex expression could be valuable here, I'm not sure they way you receive the above output but I will assume that it's a string type:

to parse the TX values:

`string = 'RX 2735118 unicast packets 703555 multicast packets 677 broadcast packets 3439365 input packets 3803190483 bytes 1867301 jumbo packets 0 storm suppression bytes 0 runts 0 giants 0 CRC 0 no buffer 0 input error 0 short frame 0 overrun 0 underrun 0 ignored 0 watchdog 0 bad etype drop 0 bad proto drop 0 if down drop 0 input with dribble 291 input discard 15 Rx pause TX 3983205 unicast packets 1916649 multicast packets 340 broadcast packets 5900194 output packets 3546311266 bytes 1702539 jumbo packets 0 output errors 0 collision 0 deferred 0 late collision 0 lost carrier 0 no carrier 0 babble 0 output discard 0 Tx pause'`

`re.findall(r'RX \d+\ ', string) #to get the matching RX values`

`re.findall(r'TX \d+\ ', string)#to get the matching TX values`

if you want to match specific values, you can make use of the re.search groups

`RX_unicast_packets = re.search(r'RX (\d+)\ \w+\ \w+\ (\d+)\ ', string).group(1)`

`RX_multicast_packets = re.search(r'RX (\d+)\ \w+\ \w+\ (\d+)\ ', string).group(2)`
let me know if you need any further help, and i would be happy to help here

Comment: Thanks @BlackHawk. following re code worked in this case.  re.findall(r'RX\n\s+ (\d+) unicast packets', string)

Comment: I want to get RX  and value before multicast packets, multipkts = re.findall(r'RX\n\s+ \w+ \d+ \s+ (\d+) multicast packets', string). Please help!

Comment: Uw, can you give me an exact example for the desired output you need

Comment: RX_unicast_packets = 2735118
RX_multicast_packets = 703555

TX_unicast_packets = 3983205
TX_multicast_packets = 1916649

Comment: In this case, you can make use of group matching in re.search, something similar to the following:

Comment: sorry i pressed enter by mistake,

Comment: RX_unicast_packets = re.search(r'RX (\d+)\ \w+\ \w+\ (\d+)\ ', string).group(1)

Comment: Thanks BlackHawk. 1st digit is easy to match, couldn't get 2nd set of digit match. RX_unicast_packets = re.search(r'RX\n \s+ (\d+) \w+\ \w+\ (\d+)', string).group(1), return NoneObject. Working:  re.search(r'RX\n \s+ (\d+) \w+\ \w+\ ', string).group(1)

Comment: strange!, this one works for me, can you please verify it again. I don't think this is related to a version mismatch `In [21]: RX_unicast_packets = re.search(r'RX (\d+)\ \w+\ \w+\ (\d+)\ ', string).group(1)

In [22]: RX_unicast_packets
Out[22]: '2735118'`